# In CSS3 is "li:hover > a" and "li a:hover" the same

Tags: html, css

is "li:hover > a" and "li a:hover" the same

such in the codes

```
ul#navigation li a:hover {
background:#f8f8f8;
color:#282828;}
```

and

```
ul#navigation li:hover > a {
background:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not at all, they are two very different selectors.

```
 li a:hover
```

**Means:** Apply those rules to the `a` element, which is **descendant** of a `li` element, when the user puts his mouse over the former.

```
 li:hover > a
```

**Means:** Apply those rules to an `a` element, which is **direct child** of a `li` element, when the user puts his mouse over the latter.

---

As you can see, there are several differences.

1. First of all, the first selector will apply the rules to the anchor, only when the anchor itself is hovered; it means that if you have an anchor element which is smaller then the parent list item, you will have to put your mouse over the anchor to trigger the changes.
2. On the other hand, the second selector applies the rule to the anchor, wherever the mouse hovers on its parent.
3. The second rule sports the `>`, also known as **direct descendant selector** or [**child selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) which will only apply the rules if the `a` tag is directly contained within the `li` with no intermediate containers.

Answer (score 1):

No,

`li:hover > a` will change the style of `a` when the  `li` is hovered, `li a:hover` will change the style of `a` when `a` is hovered.

See the diference here: http://jsfiddle.net/uzyUr/

Futher more `>` is the child selector so `a` must be a directly nested in `li` whereas the space is an any descendant selector, so `a` could be nested as deep in `li` as you like

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

In this part the element that triggers the hover would be the link.

```
ul#navigation li a:hover {
background:#f8f8f8;
color:#282828;}
```

While in here, the element that triggers the hover is the `li`

```
ul#navigation li:hover {
background:#fff;}
```

But if you have something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

both CSS would work. On the other hand, if you do something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

the 1st one won't work but the 2nd will do.

But if you have '>' like

```
ul#navigation li:hover > a{
    background:#fff;}
```

both would be technically the same for the link or `<a>` tag but,of course the `<li>` must be present before the link.

Answer (score 0):

here is the demo to understand [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p4DLZ/1/)

first hover to text then your `a` color will change to green

next hover right outside text then your `a` color will change to red

**Conclusion**

```
ul#navigation li a:hover
```

style of a will be changed when a is hovered

```
ul#navigation li:hover > a
```

style of a will be changed when li is hovered